How to mock class implementation in vitest
We have existing code that's structured similar to following which I want to test. The challenging part here is the fact that instance of Two is created at module root level in Three.ts file. This makes mocks not work. I also want to use mockImplementation inside test case because I want to manipulate the return value of runOne from test to test.
// One.ts

export class One {
  runOne() {
    return "hello";
  }
}

// Two.ts

import { One } from "./One";

export class Two {
  private one: One = new One();

  runTwo() {
    console.log(this.one);
    return console.log(this.one.runOne());
  }
}

// Three.ts

import { Two } from "./Two";

const two: Two = new Two();

export const run = () => {
  two.runTwo();
};

// main.test.ts

import { describe, Mock, test, vi } from "vitest";
import { run } from "./Three";
import { One } from "./One";

vi.mock("./One", async () => {
  return {
    One: vi.fn(),
  };
});

describe("suite", () => {
  test("test", async () => {
    const MOne = One as unknown as Mock;

    MOne.mockImplementation(() => {
      return { runOne: () => "world" };
    });

    run();
  });
});

Output:
spy {}

TypeError: this.one.runOne is not a function
 ❯ Two.runTwo __test__/Two.ts:8:33
      6|   runTwo() {
      7|     console.log(this.one);
      8|     return console.log(this.one.runOne());
       |                                 ^
      9|   }
     10| }

I want to have two test scripts where runOne returns two different values in the same test file.
describe('suite', () => {
  test('first', () => {
    // mock runOne to return "first"
    // should print "first"
    run()
  })

  test('second', () => {
    // mock runOne to return "two"
    // should print "two"
    run()
  })
})

